# Cannot set ProductBiddingCategory in google adwords api

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I use google adwords api(v 201705) in my application and when I want to set `ProductBiddingCategory` in inventory filter it does not work as it should. I have a config with the ids. I use Laravel 5.4 and php 5.6. This is for first level:

```
'category1stLevel' => array(
        '-7183678771116356049' => 'Animals & Pet Supplies',
        '-8901225909846585574' => 'Arts & Entertainment ',
        '-135859741832737125' => 'Baby & Toddler',
        '1630781044279653237' => 'Business & Industrial',
        '-4047358871470385303' => 'Cameras & Optics',
        '-3692872870547437690' => 'Clothing & Accessories',
        '-8991081036712453473' => 'Electronics',
        '-4844290245982195030' => 'Food, Beverages & Tobacco',
        '5791209622805759532' => 'Furniture',
        '1689639310991627077' => 'Hardware',
        '-1319082945867661876' => 'Health & Beauty',
        '-730821788104646261' => 'Home & Garden',
        '-5914235892932915235' => 'Luggage & Bags',
        '513743549703189181' => 'Mature',
        '-823909673284230433' => 'Media',
        '7477391641924216366' => 'Office Supplies',
        '225849170806580462' => 'Religious & Ceremonial ',
        '-7974890371279108093' => 'Software',
        '6085370270382652056' => 'Sporting Goods',
        '-136928849880388598' => 'Toys & Games',
        '-7701278134223972650' => 'Vehicles & Parts'
    )
```

and I set like this:

```
$value = new ProductBiddingCategory();
$value->setType('BIDDING_CATEGORY_L1');
$value->setValue(-7183678771116356049);
$productScope->setDimensions([$value]);
```

It seems that php is converting it to exponential number(for eg -7.18367877111636E+18) and when it sets I receive the error 'Invalid bidding category -7183678771116355789....', meaning that it is not the number from beginning. If I set like this `$value->setValue(-7.18367877111636E+18)` it also does not work.

How should I set it to work? Please help.